# ActiveMQ plugin for Grails taking over SSL connections?

Tags: grails, ssl, activemq-classic

I'm using the [ActiveMQ plugin](https://grails.org/plugin/activemq) for Grails (2.4.x) and it's messing with SSL connections. By messing with SSL connections I mean it's not allowing a client browser to connect to the Grails application using SSL.

Any attempt to connect to the SSL port (no matter what it's set to) for the web application results in `ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR` being reported by the browser.

If I disable the plugin SSL works just fine.

I've reviewed the plugin source code and I don't see anything in there that should be doing this.

I'm at a complete and total loss and it's driving me mad. I'm not sure what other information I can provide to assist others in helping me but I'm hopeful that someone out there can point me to some kind of ActiveMQ setting that I can use to disable this odd behavior.

The included libraries from the plugin are as follows:

```
activemq-broker-5.10.1.jar
activemq-client-5.10.1.jar
activemq-jms-pool-5.10.1.jar
activemq-openwire-legacy-5.10.1.jar
activemq-pool-5.10.1.jar
activemq-spring-5.10.1.jar
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out this is because Active MQ detects if the "Bouncy Castle" security provider is available on the classpath and will add it into the `java.security.Security` providers in the second position when it creates the broker.

Unfortunately there isn't an option within Active MQ to disable this feature, and it was discussed briefly in the JIRA and determined this wouldn't ever be an option.

Since this project also uses the `crypto:2.0` plugin for Grails it was loading the Bouncy Castle security provider for the JVM. As a standalone this would be fine for Active MQ to do this, but when embedded into Tomcat this was causing issues with SSL. Not sure why exactly the Bouncy Castle provider wasn't handling SSL TLS correctly, but adding the following to `BootStrap.groovy` removes it from the providers and fixes the issue.

`java.security.Security.removeProvider('BC')`

In this project we are using ActiveMQ within the virtual machine and have no need for any additional security providers for Active MQ to use for SSL connections since it won't be using them anyway.